# kafka mongo db source connector with mongo db running on kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to setup mongo db source connector [https://www.confluent.io/hub/mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb] for confluent kafka platform. I was able to successfully establish the flow between mongo db and kafka when I used Mongo DB Atlas' connection URI. Problem arises when I am using mongo db running on my azure kubernetes cluster. I have created a mongo db statefulset with 3 replicas and I have exposed the mongo db service to the internet through a load balancer. I am able to connect to the mongo db exposed on public IP by using robo 3T and do CRUD operations. Now when I use the connection URI of mongo db running in kubernetes which looks like "mongodb://load-balance-ip:27017/test?ssl=false&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority", I get the following error kafka connect logs

`INFO Failed to resume change stream: The $changeStream stage is only supported on replica sets 40573 (com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceTask:253)`

Mongo db stateful set yml looks like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: eic-mongo-mongodb
spec:
  serviceName: eic-mongo-mongodb
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eic-mongo-mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eic-mongo-mongodb
        selector: eic-mongo-mongodb
    spec:
      affinity:
        # Try to put each ES data node on a different node in the K8s cluster
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 100
              podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchExpressions:
                    - key: app
                      operator: In
                      values:
                        - eic-mongo-mongodb
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      containers:
        - name: eic-mongo-mongodb
          image: mongo:4.0.8
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: "1Gi"
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: "1Gi"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-volume
              mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mongo-volume
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        volumeMode: Filesystem
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 3Gi
```

And mongo DB service yml looks like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eic-mongo-mongodb
 ports:
  - name: "27017"
    nodePort: 31683
    port: 27017
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    app: eic-mongo-mongodb
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Can someone please let me know where I am making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to setup mongodb cluster in correct way. Please follow [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) to deploy mongodb replica set on kuberntes using operator. If you want to setup with statefulset only follow [this](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets/)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to setup mongo db source connector and sink connector using Mongo DB atlas URI and confluent kafka platform connector.
Sink connector was able successfully established.
but when i try to make Source connector, problem arised.
Could you possibly find my problem?

This is POST json data for http://localhost:8083/connectors

```
{"name": "mongo-source-cashRecord",
   "config": {
     "tasks.max":"1",
     "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
     "topic.prefix":"mymongo_joy_",
     "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
     "key.converter.schemas.enable":false,
     "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
     "value.converter.schemas.enable":false,
     "connection.uri":"mongodb+srv://userid:password@clusterjoy.iz9ag.mongodb.net/testdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
     "database":"testdb",
     "collection":"cashRecord",
     "pipeline": "[{\"$match\":{\"operationType\":{\"$in\":[\"insert\",\"update\",\"replace\"]}}}]"
}}
```